# ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))) when checking up opensearch indice

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

When I try to check if an index exist in opensearch cluster using this code:

```
self.opensearch_db.indices.exists(index = index_name)
```

I get the following error:

```
ConnectionError: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))) caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

I try connecting to opensearch cluster via postman and everything was fine.

Comment: I have to add this two parameters use_ssl=True and verify_certs=False within opensearch constructor